# PHP: set value of static property using variable

Tags: php, oop, static

How can I set the value of a static property using a variable. I am using a barcode class where you can set the barcode type as follows:

```
$generator->getBarcode($data[$barcode], $generator::TYPE_CODE_128);
```

I want the barcode type to passed in a variable like so:

```
$barcodeType = 'TYPE_CODE_39';
$generator->getBarcode($data[$barcode], $generator::$barcodeType);
```

Is this possible? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `constant()` function for this. Pass it a string in the format `class::name`:

```
$generator->getBarcode(
    $data[$barcode],
    constant(get_class($generator) . '::' . $barcodeType)
);
```